# Approximate distribution for the sample mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, central-limit-theorem

> A random variable $X$ is said to follow a discrete uniform distribution if its probability function is given by
>   $$p_X(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}\frac{1}{\theta}, & x = 1, 2, \ldots, \theta\\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}, \end{array}\right.$$
>   where $\theta$ is a positive integer. This distribution is denoted $\text{dunif[1, $\theta$]}$ in the following parts of the question.
>
> 1. Given that $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n j = \frac{1}{2}n(n + 1)$ and $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n j^2 = \frac{1}{6} n(n + 1)(2n + 1)$, find the mean and variance of this distribution.
> 2. Determine the cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$, ensuring that it is defined properly for all $x$.
> 3. The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, with $X \sim \text{dunif}[1, \theta]$ and $Y \sim \text{dunif}[1, \theta]$. Carefully apply the convolution formula to determine the probability function of $W = X + Y$.
> 4. A $20$-sided fair die is rolled as many times as necessary. Write down the probability expression that the third face $10$ turns up on the $n$<sup>th</sup> roll.
> 5. For a large $n$, what is an approximate distribution for the sample mean $\overline{X}$? Ensure that all the distribution details are given.

I've got the previous parts.

For the last part, my attempt is that it's about CLT (is this correct?) but then I am stuck.

Is the approximate distribution of sample mean Normal here?

And what are the details of such distribution?

Thank you for your help. (This is the complete question)

Comment: Looks like two fairly unrelated questions. The sample mean of what? The $n$ of the negative binomial does not seem to be connected with the $n$ of the sample size.

Comment: Maybe the second question has to do with the following problem. Toss the die $n$ times, let $X_i$ be the number on the $i$-th toss, let $\bar{X}=(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$. Then you should find the mean and variance of $X_i$. Call these $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. For large $n$, $\bar{X}$ is approximately normal mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2/n$.

Comment: Hi Andre I will post the complete question later and improve my question. Could you please take a look then ? My apologies

Comment: @user156422: I may be asleep. But someone will answer. If no one has, I will when awake. I will not know whether something has been changed unless I get pinged, in the style at the beginning of this comment.

Comment: @André Nicolas ...

Comment: @heropup  a pretty weird question please help thanks :)

Comment: @david please help me out thanks !

Comment: @M. Vinay could you please take a look at this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are being asked is as follows. Imagine tossing the die $n$ times. Let $X_i$ be the number obtained on the $i$-th toss, and let 
$$\bar{X}=\frac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}{n}$$
For large $n$, what is the approximate distribution of $\bar{X}$?

First we find the mean $\mu$ and the variance $\sigma^2$ of $X_i$.

The random variable $X_i$ has discrete uniform distribution, taking on values $1$ to $20$ each with probability $\frac{1}{20}$. It follows that 
$$\mu=\frac{1+2+\cdots+20}{20}.$$
By a formula you were given earlier in the problem, the sum $1+2+\cdots +20$ is $\frac{(20)(21)}{2}$.  It follows that $\mu=\frac{21}{2}$.

For $\sigma^2$, use the fact this is $E(X_i^2)-(E(X_i))^2$. We need to find $E(X_i^2)$. This is 
$$\frac{1^2+2^2+\cdots +20^2}{20}.$$
To find the sum of the squares, use the formula given to you for the sum of the first $n$ squares. The sum of the squares is $\frac{(20)(21)(41)}{6}$.

Now you have all the information needed to find $\sigma^2$. Divide the sum of squares by $20$, and subtract $(10.5)^2$.

Finally, the mean of $\bar{X}$ is $\mu$, and the variance of $\bar{X}$ is $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$. For largish $n$, and it does not have to be terribly large, $\bar{X}$ is approximately normal with mean, variance given in this paragraph. And yes, it is by the Central Limit Theorem that we conclude that $\bar{X}$ has approximately normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. But I think you are supposed to answer it using the main question given + part F ?

Comment: could you please take a look ? thanks

Comment: That would make no sense, as I have commented before.

Comment: does it have anything to do with order statistics ?

Comment: Nothing to do with order statistics, sample mean has a clear meaning. You do an experiment $n$ times and average the results.

Answer (score 1):

A normal distribution is determined by its mean and variance - these are the "details" you are being asked about.

So, you need to compute the expectation and variance of the sample mean and take the limit.

Your $X$ is discrete uniform; it has finite variance, so, by CLT, $\bar X$ converges to a Gaussian normal.

By linearity of expectation,
$$E(\bar X)=E(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX}{n})=\frac{\sum_iE(X)}{n}=E(X)\frac{n}{n}=E(X)$$
and one can compute the expectation
$$E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^\theta i\frac{1}{\theta}=\frac{1}{\theta}\frac{\theta(\theta-1)}{2}=\frac{\theta-1}{2}$$

Similarly for the variance - but I will leave it as an exercise to the reader (too late now, sorry).

Comment: I don't think what you've shown here is correct ? I think you are supposed to answer part g from part f + the main question instead of the main question alone ?

Comment: the letter $X$ is not mentioned in (g). also, (g) talks about an _event_, not a _random variable_.

Comment: if you take a closer look it is...

Comment: Sorry but I don't think your answer is correct. you need to answer it using Part F as well.