# Probability Generating Functions with Three Dice

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, generating-functions

> Three identical dice are thrown. The dice are fair, that is, for all three dice the probability of turning up face $j$ is $1/6$, $1 \le j \le 6$. Let $X_1,\ X_2,\ X_3$ be the independent random variables representing the numbers on dice $1$, $2$, and $3$ respectively.
>
> 1. Find the probability generating function (pgf) of $X_1$.
> 2. Let $G_Y(z)$ be the pgf of $Y = X_1 + X_2 + X_3$. Show that
>      $$
>    G_Y(z) = \dfrac{z^3 (1 - z^6)^3}{216} \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \binom{k + 2}{2} z^k.
>    $$
>      You need to specify every rule you have used.
> 3. Hence find $P(Y = 9)$.

I got the first two parts. I am having issues with the third part.

My thought is to sum the coefficients of $z^9$?

Is this the correct approach? If not, could you please demonstrate the correct approach please?

PS: Please show how to do part $3$ from part $2$ instead of computing the probability directly.

Comment: @M. Vinay  Thank you for editing my post. Could you please help me out here ?

Comment: You are right, you have to find the coefficient of $z^9$.

Comment: @M. Vinay but how do you do that from part 2 ? Could you please demonstrate please ?

Comment: It is Part $2$ that contains $G_Y(z)$, so if you use the generating function you are automatically doing it from Part $2$.

Comment: Observe that in $G_Y(z)$, the minimum power if $z^3$. So in order to $z^9$, we have to get $z^6$ from the product of $(1-z^6)^3$ and $z^k$. What is the expansion of $(1 - z^6)^3$? In this expansion, which terms can be multiplied with what $z^k$ to make $z^6$?

Comment: Thank you for your rather professional response, Mr Vinay. Could you please take a look at one question about sample mean please ? it is very weird!!  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832464/approximate-distribution-for-the-sample-mean

Answer (score 3):

Write
$$G_Y(z)=\frac{1}{216}z^3(1-3z^6+\cdots)\left(\binom22+\cdots+\binom82z^6+\cdots\right)\ .$$
The coefficient of $z^9$ is
$$\frac{\binom82-3\binom22}{216}=\frac{25}{216}$$
and this is the required probability.

Comment: Are you missing something after the 2C2? Should there be a z term ?

Comment: There will be a term $\binom32z$, but we don't need it for this question.

Comment: could you take a look at this please ? I think none of them are giving the correct methods...     http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832464/approximate-distribution-for-the-sample-mean

Comment: @M. Vinay here is the link to that question   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832464/approximate-distribution-for-the-sample-mean

Answer (score 2):

From Part $2$, we have $$G_Y(z) = \dfrac{z^3(1 - z^6)^3}{216} \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \binom{k + 2}{2}z^k.$$

$P(Y = 9)$ is the coefficient of $z^9$ in $G_Y(z)$. As the least degee term of $G_Y(z)$ is $z^3$, we can ignore the $z^3$ in the above formula and find the coefficient of $z^6$ from the remaining terms $(1 - z^6)^3$ and $z^k$ (for appropriate $k$).

Now, $(1 - z^6)^3 = 1 - 3z^6 + \ldots$ (where $\ldots$ are terms of degree higher than $6$). To get $z^6$, the first term $1$ can be multiplied by $z^6$ (by taking $k = 6$ in $z^k$) and the second can be multiplied by $1$ (by taking $k = 0$). Thus, the coefficient of $z^9$ in $G_Y(z)$ is

$$
 \dfrac{1}{216} \left[ \binom{8}{2} - 3\binom{2}{2} \right]
= \dfrac{25}{216}
$$
$\therefore \boxed{P(Y = 9) = \dfrac{25}{216}}$